# How to execute a python script and leave open a shell for further testing in VIM

Tags: python, shell, vim

When I write python script in VIM I would like to test them into VIM directly I know that I can use:

`w !python -`

But this execute the script and suddenly close the shell so if I want to test a function I can't call it with various arguments!
For example if I have this code:

```
print "How can I test the following function in Vim?"
def testfunc(test):
    print test*2
```

When I run in VIM `w !python -` it print me the print statement but I can't try to test the function with some arbitrary arguments. How can I run the script in a python shell for further testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a Python script and then immediately switch to interactive mode with the `-i` flag:

```
python -i test.py
```

Comment: Perfect now i use `:!python -i %`and it works great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You may run interactive buffer like Conque Term with python commandline and then just import your .py file in it.